ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeBaseModel' from 'langchain_core.utils.pydantic'
from pydantic import BaseModel
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,chain_type="stuff",retriever=retriever,input_key="query",return_source_documents=True)+

.....
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypeBaseModel' from 'langchain_core.utils.pydantic' (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\utils\pydantic.py)

!pip install pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA`your text`


Have you tried updating langchain and pydantic to their latest versions?
